# Force quitting the software manager causes Linux Mint 9 windows to turn black and white

Tags: start-menu, linux-mint, colors

Whenever I force quit an application such as the software manager it causes my taskbar previews to turn black and white and the mint menu turns black and white. Most system applications and notifications are in black in white. The only way to fix is to log out and log back in.

Info:

- Linux Mint 9 (Isadora)
- GNOME 2.30.0

Example of effect:

[image: System Monitor in B&W]

Comment: Whats the CPU usage? What application are you killing?

Comment: I didn't check my CPU usage but I know it isn't max. I have a dual-core processor. When I try to kill the software manager because it stops responding and becomes grayed out.